# Foreach loop not working as expected in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am getting array in foreach loop,There are two keys "sequence"(unique,not repeated) and "asset_type"(can duplicate/same)
And i want to run loop with every "sequence" with every "asset_type",i want to execute my loop like following way so i can check every "sequence"
with every "asset_type"

```
sequence            asset_type
1                   1
1                   2
1                   n (last asset_type)
...

2                   1
2                   1
2                   n(last asset_type)
n(last sequence)    n(last sequence)
```

My current array is like

```
Array
(
    [id] => 78
    [sequence] => 1
    [asset_type] => 8
)
(
    [id] => 3
    [sequence] => 2
    [asset_type] => 11
)
(
    [id] => 3
    [sequence] => 3
    [asset_type] => 25
)
```

Here is my current code (static),How can i check every "sequence" with every "asset_type"(dynamically instead of static) ?

```
foreach ($feed as $key=> $fd) {
case ($fd['sequence'] == "1"):
 if ($fd['sequence'] == "1" && $fd['asset_type'] == "8") {
 // if condition match then ....
 }
 break;
```

Comment: Something is wrong in your description. If your sequence really is unique and not repeated as you claim, then the whole question makes no sense, since "every sequence with every asset_type" will be exactly the set of asset_types.

Comment: @arkascha: i want to make condition,for example if sequence=1 and asset type=1,if sequence=1 and asset type=2... and so on

Comment: @Ritika Isn't it just 2 nested for loops.. See here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6fa12f62c0d48c2882ebc4cff2327b69b529ae3b

Comment: That is not an answer to my remark, sorry. You need to fix your question, your description, not add further details in comments. Now is your sequence unique and not repeating or is it not?

Comment: @arkascha: "sequence" will be unique but "asset_type" can repeat

Comment: @nice_dev: your code is working but how can i remove duplicate "asset_type" because as you know "sequence" is unique so 1 "sequence" related with 1 "asset_type",Kindly remove "duplicate" value

Comment: If so, then what does your first block in the question show? The sequence definitely is _not_ unique in there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 nested loops to do this. To print only unique combinations of sequence-asset type values, you can make use of a new associative array, say `$set`. Make a string key separated by pipe(`|`) symbol. If this key doesn't exist in `$set`, add the key and print the combination, else, skip it.

```
<?php

$data = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 78,
    'sequence' => 1,
    'asset_type' => 8,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'sequence' => 2,
    'asset_type' => 11,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 3,
    'sequence' => 3,
    'asset_type' => 25,
  ),
);

$set = [];

foreach($data as $value){
  foreach($data as $cousin_value){
    $pair = $value['sequence'] . "|" . $cousin_value['asset_type'];
    if(!isset($set[$pair])){
        $set[$pair] = true;
        echo $value['sequence']," ",$cousin_value['asset_type'],PHP_EOL;   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: code is fine but how can i use "condition" (if condition) ?

Comment: @Ritika From where did if condition come into picture? What are you trying to achieve with if conditions?

Comment: i want to show html code based on condition, for example....after your code i am getting "sequence" with "asset_type" which is fine but now i want to make condition like "if sequence='1'" and "asse_type" ="8" (check from array which i ma getting) then <!-- show html code--> so like this i will use condition and show html code (according to array/database)

Comment: @ritika but if there are 200 such combinations, you can't afford to write 200 if conditions.

Comment: you are right but can i use following code ? is this right ? according to me its working,i am using this line below "second foreach loop" , its dynamic 

if($value['sequence']==$sequencess && $cousin_value['asset_type']==$asset_types)
  {
   echo "show html code here";
  }

Comment: @Ritika Yeah, looks fine to me.

Comment: but condition not matching correctly, can we match condition ? where i am wrong ?

Comment: @Ritika I am sorry. I don't think I follow you anymore. Perhaps, put a new question with this new requirement and accept my answer if it solved your first problem.